# sequence number generation function in AWS redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there a sequence number generation function in redshift ? Or a function that takes combination of values and gives out a numerical hash key ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no concept of sequences (as seen in Oracle) at the moment.

You have a few options:

- Number tables
- RANK() or ROW_NUMBER() window functions over the whole set. Note that this can have some negative performance implications if you have a multi-node cluster.
- Columns defined as IDENTITY(seed, step). Note that IDENTITY sequence may be 'sparse' (e.g. have gaps in the sequence).

Comment: We have multinode redshift cluster. IDENTITY - is expected to provide unique values without collision ?

Comment: Yes, IDENTITY values will not collide but they are not guaranteed to be contiguous, e.g., you'll get a run of values like 1,9,17,25 for an 8 node cluster.

Comment: In my case, always i have to keep incrementing the value whenever i run the sql. So, i used Max(existing sequence from target) + row_number()... Hope it helps to someone

Answer (score 9):

Here is another way to generate 1 million numbers

```
with seq_0_9 as (
select 0 as num
union all select 1 as num
union all select 2 as num
union all select 3 as num
union all select 4 as num
union all select 5 as num
union all select 6 as num
union all select 7 as num
union all select 8 as num
union all select 9 as num
), seq_0_999 as (
select a.num + b.num * 10 + c.num * 100 as num
from seq_0_9 a, seq_0_9 b, seq_0_9 c
)
select a.num + b.num * 1000 as num
from seq_0_999 a, seq_0_999 b
order by num
```

Answer (score 2):

I am new to Redshift, and I found this article looking for a common sequence, that is not supported on Amazon database. I found this solution I will report with a complete example using **ROW_NUMBER**.

I have schemas *sta* and *dim*. In *sta* I have staging tables, while in *dim* I have dimension tables I want to populate with ids. I have a source of information that has fields **trk_key**, **name** containing for instance some publishers.

```
CREATE TABLE sta.publisher (
        trk_key VARCHAR(20),
        name VARCHAR(225)
);
CREATE TABLE dim.publisher (
        id SMALLINT,
        trk_key VARCHAR(20),
        name VARCHAR(255),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

First I truncate *sta.publisher* table and load there a csv file. Then I launch the following query

```
-- This query is idempotent:
-- it will insert a publisher found in sta.publisher table only if
-- it is not already in dim.publisher table.
INSERT INTO dim.publisher
SELECT
        -- Generate id using max id found in dim.publisher.
        -- Start with id=1 if dim.publisher is empty.
        (
                SELECT NVL(MAX(id), 0)
                FROM dim.publisher
        ) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
        trk_key,
        name
FROM sta.publisher
        -- Only insert record if trk_key is not found in dim.publisher table.
        WHERE trk_key NOT IN (
                SELECT trk_key
                FROM dim.publisher
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still query the Posgres function `generate_series(start, stop, step)`

But it isn't a supported function and can only run on the leader node, which makes it fairly useless, but hey you can still `select generate_series(1,100)` and get a list of 100 numbers. You just can't do anything with that function *not* on the leader node.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html