# REDSHIFT: How can I generate a series of numbers without creating a table called "numbers" in redshift (Postgres 8.0.2)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, generate-series, postgresql-8.0

I need to create an empty time table series for a report so I can left join activity from several tables to it. Every hour of the day does not necessarily have data, but I want it to show null or zero for inactivity instead of omitting that hour of the day.

In later versions of Postgres (post 8.0.2), this is easy in several ways:

`SELECT unnest(array[0,1,2,3,4...]) as numbers`

OR

`CROSS JOIN (select generate_series as hours
            from generate_series(now()::timestamp,
                                 now()::timestamp + interval '1 day',
                                 '1 hour'::interval
            )) date_series`

Redshift can run some of these commands, but throws an error when you attempt to run it in conjunction with any of the tables.

**WHAT I NEED:**

A reliable way to generate a series of numbers (e.g. 0-23) *as a subquery* that will run on redshift (uses postgres 8.0.2).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34167753/3019685

Comment: Because Redshift, is not versioned and thus the older version can not ever be used by anyone I can't see why this question should stay open. I'm voting to close. Redshift now supports this.

Comment: Evan Carroll, Redshift does not support cross join into subquery with generate series. It shows error "Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;"

Comment: @EvanCarroll is the support for this documented somewhere? I still see generate_series listed as "unsupported" on the redshift docs. We migrated to bigquery so I can't test it myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sequence number generation function in AWS redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643338/sequence-number-generation-function-in-aws-redshift)

Comment: no @SteveChambers the question is very similar, but less specific. The existing workarounds and proposed solutions are all painful to use, since none of them are reliable or versatile. I haven't used redshift in a year or two, so it's possible they've added functionality to address this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As long as you have a table that has more rows than your required series has numbers, this is what has worked for me in the past:

```sql
select
    (row_number() over (order by 1)) - 1 as hour
from
    large_table
limit 24
;
```

Which returns numbers `0-23`.

Comment: This is a decent solution, and if I use something like pg_catalog.pg_operator, I don't have to worry about schema changes ruining the query.

Comment: ugly but effective

Comment: And cross join it again to get more values (pg_operator only had 647 objects).

Answer (score 5):

[Recursion was released for Redshift in April 2021.](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/amazon-redshift-announces-support-for-hierarchical-data-queries-with-recursive-cte/) Now that recursion is possible in Redshift. You can generate series of numbers (or even table) with below code

```
with recursive numbers(NUMBER) as
(
select 1 UNION ALL
select NUMBER + 1 from numbers where NUMBER < 28
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Amazon Redshift does not allow use of `generate_series()` for table functions. The workaround seems to be creating a table of numbers.

See also:

- [Using sql function generate_series() in redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282276/using-sql-function-generate-series-in-redshift)
- [Generate Series in Redshift and MySQL](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/generate-series-in-redshift-and-mysql.html), which does not seem correct but does introduce some interesting ideas

Comment: Creating a table of numbers irks me in a very terrible way. It feels like writing the numbers out one by one in a python script. It's just wrong.

Comment: You could create a `date` table, with columns such as `DayOfWeek`, `PublicHoliday`, `Month`, `Quarter`, etc. This is a common practice to extract useful information from dates. Then, you could re-use this table as a `Numbers` table without feeling so irksome.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of querying a system table just to get a list of row numbers. If it's something constant and small enough like hours of a day, I would go with plain old `UNION ALL`:

```
WITH 
  hours_in_day AS (
    SELECT 0 AS hour
    UNION ALL SELECT 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 4
    ...
    UNION ALL SELECT 23
  )
```

And then join`hours_in_day` to whatever you want to.

Comment: I've actually had better luck querying a very small table and selecting row_number() over (). Redshift doesn't play nice with repeated UNION ALL sub queries, and even for something as small as hours of the day, we've seen better performance with row_number.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643338/sequence-number-generation-function-in-aws-redshift#answer-35500173) also describes how this can be adapted with `CROSS JOIN`s to generate far more numbers.