# Amazon Redshift: How to create a table containing time series

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to create a table in Redshift which will have a column `date` whose values will be from today to next 3 years.

```
        date         
---------------------
 2017-05-03 00:00:00
 2017-05-04 00:00:00
 2017-05-05 00:00:00
 2017-05-06 00:00:00
```

I am trying to do this using a `create table as select_query` statement.

```
 create table tmp_date_series as select now()::date::timestamp + generate_series(0, 1000);
```

However, the above query fails with an error -

```
INFO:  Function "now()" not supported.
INFO:  Function "generate_series(integer,integer)" not supported.
ERROR:  Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
```

But if I run the select query alone - `select now()::date::timestamp + generate_series(0, 150) as date;`, it runs without any error-

```
        date         
---------------------
 2017-05-03 00:00:00
 2017-05-04 00:00:00
 2017-05-05 00:00:00
```

Any idea how do I create such a table?

Comment: Voting to reopen, `generate_series` is not available on AWS Redshift.

Comment: Shouldn't `generate_series()` go into the `from` clause? `create table x as select (current_date + i)::timestamp from generate_series(0,1000) as x(i)`

Comment: As an aside, the query in your question that actually works only does because it runs solely on the leader node, which uses a fork of PostgreSQL 8.4. As soon as you hit the worker nodes (for instance if you use any 'real' table), the query runs on those, which do not have `generate_series`.

Comment: Instead of `generate_series` you have to use a table with numbers or a cte. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667215/redshift-how-can-i-generate-a-series-of-numbers-without-creating-a-table-called

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282276/using-sql-function-generate-series-in-redshift

Comment: @marth Looks like postgres support it [now](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33577864/3470178) but im not in position to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `generate_series` isn't supported in Redshift.

My team is using a CTE like this to get a series of consecutive dates starting from a particular date:

```
with dates as (
    select
        (trunc(getdate()) + row_number() over (order by 1))::date as date
    from
        large_enough_table
    limit
        150
)
```

Then you can use it as:

```
select date
from dates
order by date
limit 5
```

And get:

```
2018-12-13
2018-12-14
...
```