# how to convert a dataset list to a set of rows in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have data set that I am uploading in to two columns in a Redshift database table:

```
{A, 1|2|3|4}
```

Once loaded into a table I need to convert it to a set of rows and insert it into another table:

```
{A, 1},{A,2},{A,3},{A,4}
```

I am wondering if there is a specific function in Redshift that I can use or if there is a specific SQL plan anyone has written to perform this type of conversion. Any help is appreciated.

NOTES:
The data in the second column can vary in range from 1 data point to 1000 data points.

Comment: You write *"uploading in to two columns in a Postgresql database table"*, yet I see the Redshift tag. What is it Postgres or Redshift?

Comment: Edited: Redshift which is a version of postgresql db.

Comment: Nope, Redshift is a fork based on the ancient PostgreSQL version 8.0. It's ok to tag the question [postgres] additionally, but be clear about your actual RDBMS and version.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT2: Redshift doesn't support Function nor Triggers so the below is only useful if you are using a PostgreSQL database**

---

EDIT: The following function can be called to do the insert and it should do what you need, after adapting it to your schema

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_function(title TEXT, data TEXT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_one(title, data) VALUES (title, data);
    INSERT INTO table_two(title, data) SELECT title, unnest(string_to_array(data, '|'));
    RETURN TRUE;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

To do an insert you would do the following:

```
SELECT insert_function('A', '1|2|3');
```

---

You will need to adapt the following Function and Trigger to fit your schema but it should do what you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_function()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_two(title, data) SELECT NEW.title, unnest(string_to_array(NEW.data, '|'));
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON table_one FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_function();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Amazon Redshift does not support Triggers. See: [Unsupported PostgreSQL Features](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html)

Comment: I could not get unnest() to work in Redshift. It doesn't appear supported.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of some code from @Charles Lee on [sequence number generation function in AWS redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643338/sequence-number-generation-function-in-aws-redshift):

First, **create a table with the values 0 to 1000**. This is required because the `generate_series()` function cannot operate at the table-level.

```
with seq_0_9 as (
select 0 as num
union all select 1 as num
union all select 2 as num
union all select 3 as num
union all select 4 as num
union all select 5 as num
union all select 6 as num
union all select 7 as num
union all select 8 as num
union all select 9 as num
)
select a.num + b.num * 10 + c.num * 100 as num
INTO numbers
from seq_0_9 a, seq_0_9 b, seq_0_9 c
order by num
```

Let's create your **input table**:

```
CREATE TABLE one (a text, b text);
INSERT INTO one VALUES ('A', '1|2|3|4');
```

Then, **extract every combination** of the first column and the split values in the second column:

```
CREATE TABLE two AS
SELECT
  a,
  split_part(b, '|', num) AS b
FROM one, numbers
WHERE
  num >0
  AND split_part(b, '|', num) != ''
```

The **result** in table two is:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
A 4
```