# How to split data from two columns using two different delimiters in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-redshift, delimiter

I have a `CTE` that has data like this. It follows two formats pretty much where `counts` and `process_ids` will have these two types of data.

```
client_id      day              counts      process_ids
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc1          Feb-01-2021        3        C1,C2 | C3,C4,C5 | C6,C7
abc2          Feb-05-2021       2, 3      C10,C11,C12 | C13,C14 # C15,C16 | C17,C18
```

Now I want to get this below output from the above `CTE` after splitting it out on `counts` and `process_ids` -

```
client_id      day              counts      process_ids
--------------------------------------------------------
abc1           Feb-01-2021        3           C1
abc1           Feb-01-2021        3           C2
abc1           Feb-01-2021        3           C3
abc1           Feb-01-2021        3           C4
abc1           Feb-01-2021        3           C5
abc1           Feb-01-2021        3           C6
abc1           Feb-01-2021        3           C7
abc2           Feb-05-2021        2           C10
abc2           Feb-05-2021        2           C11
abc2           Feb-05-2021        2           C12
abc2           Feb-05-2021        2           C13
abc2           Feb-05-2021        2           C14
abc2           Feb-05-2021        3           C15
abc2           Feb-05-2021        3           C16
abc2           Feb-05-2021        3           C17
abc2           Feb-05-2021        3           C18
```

Basically, the idea is to split `counts` and `process_ids` basis on the below two use cases if they follow any of those formats.

**UseCase 1**

If `counts` column only has single-digit and `process_ids` column has `|` delimiter.

[image]

**UseCase 2**

If `counts` column only has two-digit separated by a `,` delimiter and `process_ids` column has `#` delimiter along with `pipe`.

[image]

I am working with `Amazon Redshift` here and I am confused about how can I split them out as needed.

Is this possible to do by any chance?

Comment: Do you have any queries you’ve attempted and their output or error message?

Comment: I am kind confuse here on what methods I am suppose to use to make this work. I tried reading on how to use regex split but couldn't fully understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might look a bit hairy at first sight but has been built up from solid techniques and gives the desired result...

### SQL

```
WITH seq_0_9 AS (
  SELECT 0 AS d
  UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS d
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS d
  UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS d
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS d
  UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS d
  UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS d
  UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS d
  UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS d
  UNION ALL SELECT 9 AS d
),
numbers AS (
  SELECT a.d + b.d * 10 + c.d * 100 + 1 AS n
  FROM seq_0_9 a, seq_0_9 b, seq_0_9 c
),
processed AS
  (SELECT client_id,
          day,
          REPLACE(counts, ' ', '') AS counts,
          REPLACE(REPLACE(process_ids, ' ', ''), '|', ',') AS process_ids
   FROM tbl),
split_pids AS
  (SELECT
     client_id, 
     day,
     counts,
     split_part(process_ids, '#', n) AS process_ids,
     n AS n1
   FROM processed
   CROSS JOIN numbers
   WHERE 
     split_part(process_ids, '#', n) IS NOT NULL
     AND split_part(process_ids, '#', n) != ''),
split_counts AS
  (SELECT
     client_id, 
     day,
     split_part(counts, ',', n) AS counts,
     process_ids,
     n1,
     n AS n2
   FROM split_pids
   CROSS JOIN numbers
   WHERE
     split_part(counts, ',', n) IS NOT NULL
     and split_part(counts, ',', n) != ''),
matched_up AS
  (SELECT * FROM split_counts WHERE n1 = n2)
SELECT
  client_id, 
  day,
  counts,
  split_part(process_ids, ',', n) AS process_ids
FROM
  matched_up
CROSS JOIN
  numbers
WHERE
  split_part(process_ids, ',', n) IS NOT NULL
  AND split_part(process_ids, ',', n) != '';
```

### Demo

Online rextester demo (using PostgreSQL but should be compatible with Redshift): https://rextester.com/FNA16497

### Brief Explanation

[This technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643338#answer-35500173) is used to generate a numbers table (from 1 to 1000 inclusive). [This technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112389#31998832) is then used multiple times with multiple [Common Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html) to achieve it in a single SQL statement.

Comment: Great answer!  One issue will be that in Redshift generate_series() is a leader node only function and cannot be joined to other data.  This isn't a big deal b/c there are a number of alternative ways to create numeric series on Redshift. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643338/sequence-number-generation-function-in-aws-redshift or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667215/redshift-how-can-i-generate-a-series-of-numbers-without-creating-a-table-called for example.

Comment: I tried running your suggestion but I am getting an error as `Invalid input syntax for integer : "g"`. Any idea why it could be and how I can resolve it? Looks like this is different between redshift and postgresql @SteveChambers

Comment: Good spot - Redshift's `REGEXP_REPLACE` function doesn't have the flag parameter and it looks like all replacements are made by default without needing the `g` global flag. I've now simplified the SQL to use the `REPLACE` function instead - as from your examples it could just trim the spaces rather than the more general case of whitespace.

Comment: That makes sense. After replacing those now I am getting different error as `UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE :: Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;`. I am not sure what it means. Also in your example you have `tbl` as a table but in my case that's a `CTE` with required columns as mentioned in my question so I replaced `tbl` with my CTE name. Any idea what is wrong here? @SteveChambers

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue but found something [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_sql-functions-leader-node.html). Is this related to what @BillWeiner said above?

Comment: Any idea on how we can fix this error? @SteveChambers

Comment: Yes, this is the error message you get when running a leader-node only function in combination with compute node data.  The answers I posted above have approaches to generate a series of numbers w/o the generate_series() function.  Since you are looking to make the numbers between 1 and 100, the easiest approach is to make a CTE with the numbers 0-9, cross join it with itself, use each source a a digit (tens and ones) and then add 1 (to get 1-100 instead of 0-99).  I can code this out if you need

Comment: @BillWeiner sure. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I've adapted the answer to generate a numbers table from one of the links provided by @BillWeiner. Hopefully it will now live up to the promise of being compatible with Redshift but please post again if it doesn't :-)

Comment: Perfect @SteveChambers.  Thanks for coding it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have built an example script, starting from this TSV

```
client_id   day counts  process_ids
abc1    Feb-01-2021 3   C1,C2 | C3,C4,C5 | C6,C7
abc2    Feb-05-2021 2,3 C10,C11,C12 | C13,C14 # C15,C16 | C17,C18
```

This is the pretty printed version

```
+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
| client_id | day         | counts | process_ids                               |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
| abc1      | Feb-01-2021 | 3      | C1,C2 | C3,C4,C5 | C6,C7                  |
| abc2      | Feb-05-2021 | 2,3    | C10,C11,C12 | C13,C14 # C15,C16 | C17,C18 |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
```

I have written this [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) procedure

```sh
mlr --tsv clean-whitespace then put -S '
  if ($process_ids=~"|" && $counts=~"^[0-9]$")
    {$process_ids=gsub($process_ids," *[|] *",",")}
  elif($process_ids=~"[#]")
    {$process_ids=gsub(gsub($process_ids," *[|] *",",")," *# *","#");$counts=gsub($counts,",","#")}'  then \
put '
  asplits = splitnv($counts, "#");
  bsplits = splitnv($process_ids, "#");
  n = length(asplits);
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += 1) {
    outrec = $*;
    outrec["counts"] = asplits[i];
    outrec["process_ids"] = bsplits[i];
    emit outrec;
  }
' then \
uniq -a then \
filter -x -S '$counts=~"[#]"' then \
cat -n then \
nest --explode --values --across-records -f process_ids --nested-fs "," then \
cut -x -f n input.tsv
```

that gives you

```
client_id       day     counts  process_ids
abc1    Feb-01-2021     3       C1
abc1    Feb-01-2021     3       C2
abc1    Feb-01-2021     3       C3
abc1    Feb-01-2021     3       C4
abc1    Feb-01-2021     3       C5
abc1    Feb-01-2021     3       C6
abc1    Feb-01-2021     3       C7
abc2    Feb-05-2021     2       C10
abc2    Feb-05-2021     2       C11
abc2    Feb-05-2021     2       C12
abc2    Feb-05-2021     2       C13
abc2    Feb-05-2021     2       C14
abc2    Feb-05-2021     3       C15
abc2    Feb-05-2021     3       C16
abc2    Feb-05-2021     3       C17
abc2    Feb-05-2021     3       C18
```